# ionic: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

When trying to build my project using Terminal as:

```
ionic build
```

I am getting the following error

> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token < You may not have the required environment or OS to run this
>   project

Comment: is it working in `ionic serve --lab`?

Comment: it is working when i type ionic serve --lab.. But when i try to run on mobile either using ionic upload or ionic build i am getting the above error

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Git hub, because when i pull code from co-member there is a git head that is created causing that error. Once we remove the Git Head everywhere the app builds correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Install the ios and/or android SDK in your system and Add platform to your ionic project `ionic platform add <OS>` .
Then try executing `ionic build <OS>`